# Objects in instance-variable list not being retained? Pointer issues?

Tags: c++

I have a global variable `vector<BezierPatch*> listOfBezierPatches` that I populate from a command line parsing function. I then have a series of methods that populates two instance variable lists of a `BezierPatch`:

```
// final list of subdivided triangles, ready to feed to OpenGL display system
std::vector<Triangle*> listOfTriangles;

// list of differential geometries (i.e. points) that we are evaluating the given patch at
std::vector<DifferentialGeometry*> listOfDifferentialGeometries;
```

main.cpp:

```
void parseBezierFile(string filename) {
    ...
    BezierPatch* currentBezierPatch = new BezierPatch();
    while (getline(file, str)) {
        ...
        vector<Eigen::Vector3f> bezierCurve;
        bezierCurve.push_back(vector_from_command_line);
        ...
        currentBezierPatch->addCurve(bezierCurve);
        ...
        listOfBezierPatches.push_back(currentBezierPatch);            
    }

    perform_subdivision();    
}

void perform_subdivision() {
    // Iterate through each of the Bezier patches...
    for (std::vector<BezierPatch*>::size_type i = 0; i < listOfBezierPatches.size(); i++) {
        BezierPatch currentBezierPatch = *(listOfBezierPatches[i]);
        currentBezierPatch.performUniformSubdivision(subdivisionParameter);
    }
}
```

BezierPatch.h:

```
void performUniformSubdivision(float stepSize) {
        int numberOfSteps = 1.0 / stepSize;
        for (int u = 0; u < numberOfSteps; u++) {
            for (int v = 0; v < numberOfSteps; v++) {
                listOfDifferentialGeometries.push_back(evaluateDifferentialGeometry(u * stepSize, v * stepSize));
            }
        }

        // Iterate through all of our differential geometries, but do NOT touch the right-most column and the bottom-most row
        for (int u = 0; u < (numberOfSteps - 1); u++) {
            for (int v = 0; v < (numberOfSteps - 1); v++) {
                // (u, v) represents the index in the above grid that we're triangulating
                // This index represents the TOP LEFT corner of the 4-point rectangle that is described above

                // Index of listOfDifferentialGeometries that corresponds with position (u, v)
                int differentialGeometrixIndex = (u * numberOfSteps) + v;

                // Construct tri-1
                listOfTriangles.push_back(new Triangle(
                        *listOfDifferentialGeometries[differentialGeometrixIndex], // top left
                        *listOfDifferentialGeometries[differentialGeometrixIndex + numberOfSteps], // move one unit right
                        *listOfDifferentialGeometries[differentialGeometrixIndex + 1])); // move one unit down from top left

                // Construct tri-2
                listOfTriangles.push_back(new Triangle(
                        *listOfDifferentialGeometries[differentialGeometrixIndex + numberOfSteps], // top right
                        *listOfDifferentialGeometries[differentialGeometrixIndex + 1], // bottom left
                        *listOfDifferentialGeometries[differentialGeometrixIndex + numberOfSteps + 1])); // bottom right
            }
        }

        // We should have (numberOfSteps - 1) * (numberOfSteps - 1) * 2 triangles
    }

DifferentialGeometry* evaluateDifferentialGeometry(float u, float v) {
    ...
    return new DifferentialGeometry(finalVCurve.point, normal, Eigen::Vector2f(u, v));
}
```

**The problem:**

After all of the above code has been run, if I iterate through the BezierPatches in `listOfBezierPatches`, the `listOfTriangles` and `listOfDifferentialGeometries` are both empty. I know this is obviously something to do with local pointers/variables, but I can't seem to figure it out. Here's a detailed look at the `perform_subdivision` method, where the problem occurs:

```
void perform_subdivision(bool adaptive_subdivision) {
    // Iterate through each of the Bezier patches...
    for (std::vector<BezierPatch*>::size_type i = 0; i < listOfBezierPatches.size(); i++) {
        BezierPatch currentBezierPatch = *(listOfBezierPatches[i]);
        currentBezierPatch.performUniformSubdivision(subdivisionParameter);

            // ***** TESTING: This successfully prints out our differential geometries ***** //
            // Iterate through Triangles in the current Bezier patch
            for (std::vector<DifferentialGeometry>::size_type j = 0; j < currentBezierPatch.listOfDifferentialGeometries.size(); j++) {
                DifferentialGeometry* currentDifferentialGeometry = currentBezierPatch.listOfDifferentialGeometries[j];
                cout << "    DifferentialGeometry " << (j + 1) << ":\n";
                Eigen::Vector3f currentPosition = currentDifferentialGeometry->position;
                cout << "      (" << currentPosition.x() << " , " << currentPosition.y() << " , " << currentPosition.z() << ")\n";
            }

            // This does NOT successfully print out our differential geometries...
            printDifferentialGeometriesInBezierPatches();    
        }
    }    
}
```

where `printDifferentialGeometriesInBezierPatches()` is defined as:

```
//****************************************************
// function that prints all differential geometries in every Bezier Patch
//***************************************************
void printDifferentialGeometriesInBezierPatches() {
    if (debug) {
        // Iterate through Bezier Patches
        for (std::vector<BezierPatch*>::size_type i = 0; i < listOfBezierPatches.size(); i++) {
            cout << "  Bezier patch " << (i + 1) << ":\n\n";

            // Iterate through Triangles in the current Bezier patch
            for (std::vector<DifferentialGeometry>::size_type j = 0; i < listOfBezierPatches[i]->listOfDifferentialGeometries.size(); j++) {
                DifferentialGeometry* currentDifferentialGeometry = listOfBezierPatches[i]->listOfDifferentialGeometries[j];
                cout << "    DifferentialGeometry " << (j + 1) << ":\n";
                Eigen::Vector3f currentPosition = currentDifferentialGeometry->position;
                cout << "      (" << currentPosition.x() << " , " << currentPosition.y() << " , " << currentPosition.z() << ")\n";
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Well, you probably need to show us some of the classes and their copy constructors. Functions like `push_back` copy the object.

Comment: I am using the compiler defined default copy constructor for `DifferentialGeometry` and `Triangle` -- both of these classes have no instance variables that are pointers. A `Triangle` has three `DifferentialGeometry` instance variables, and a `DifferentialGeometry` has two `Eigen::Vector3f` instance variables.

Comment: @RyanYu `both of these classes have no instance variables that are pointers.`  So why do you have a vector of pointers for those types?  Why not simply `std::vector<Triangle>` and `std::vector<DifferentialGeometry>`?  The same thing with all of your vectors -- why not just use objects and forget the pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem in the next line in `perform_subdivision`

```
BezierPatch currentBezierPatch = *(listOfBezierPatches[i]);
```

For each element you create a copy which removed in the end of the loop

```
void perform_subdivision() {
    // Iterate through each of the Bezier patches...
    for (std::vector<BezierPatch*>::size_type i = 0; i < listOfBezierPatches.size(); i++) {
        // ! Here  you create a copy of i-th element
        BezierPatch currentBezierPatch = *(listOfBezierPatches[i]);
        // populate its memebers
        currentBezierPatch.performUniformSubdivision(subdivisionParameter);
    }
}
```

I guess this would be correct

```
void perform_subdivision() {
    // Iterate through each of the Bezier patches...
    for (std::vector<BezierPatch*>::size_type i = 0; i < listOfBezierPatches.size(); i++) {
        BezierPatch* currentBezierPatch = listOfBezierPatches[i];
        currentBezierPatch->performUniformSubdivision(subdivisionParameter);
    }
}
```